# Why does below Dynamic Query returns NULL?

Tags: sql-server

Why below Query Returns null instead of a dynamic query??

```
declare @Query Nvarchar(2000),
@IdentificationNo Nvarchar(255)=NULL

Set @Query='select VD.* from VWNROCDetail VD Where' 
Set @Query=@Query+'((NROCApplicationId like ''%' + @IdentificationNo + '%'')OR (ISNULL('''+@IdentificationNo+''','''') = ''''))'

select @Query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because @IdentificationNo is NULL. You need to use COALESCE(@IdentificationNo, '') or something like that.

```
'A' + NULL + 'B'
```

Returns Null
Whereas

```
'A' + '' + 'B'
```

returns 'AB'

Comment: I'm not a SQL person. This seems like a basic stuff. Helped to save my time. Thanks.

Comment: apologies, I assumed you knew about sp_executesql but couldn't understand why your variable was null.

Comment: This was just a peace of a long stored procedure. I have to use "In" clause in my query and the input will be passed as @parameter. So What i'm doing a coordination and execute. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Be careful - if you can avoid the dynamic SQL it is better because the stored procedure can precompile its path, whereas dynamic queries have to be recompiled each time. If performance is an issue, have a look at this. It might be unavoidable, but good to know if you are inexperienced.

Answer (score 1):

The result ist null in String concatenation.Because  your variable @IdentificationNo is null. If you append NULL to any String, the result is always NULL.

Not sure what you are trying to archive, but you should take a look at the sp_executesql procedure.
Example:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'《your statement using @p1 as variable》', N'@p1 NVARCHAR(255)', @p1 = @IdentificationNo;
```

If you explain the Statement, i could offer some help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree Alan. Now, it's really necessary to build a query with concantenation? In your case you can just do it :

```
declare @IdentificationNo Nvarchar(255)=NULL;

select VD.* from VWNROCDetail VD 
Where VD.NROCApplicationId like '%' + @IdentificationNo + '%' or @IdentificationNo is null ;
```

Comment: So, you don't need to declare `@Query` at all